# How do I make a text search box that searches for any part of the criteria in Access 2007?

Tags: ms-access-2007, search-box

I have a database in Access 2007 and I am currently using the following code for the text search box.  My problem is that it will only find the record if the entire name is typed in to the search box.  In the case of a business name, I would like the user to be able to type in the first word of the business and it retrieve the record on the form.  Currently, if I type in the first name, it says the record cannot be found.  I have to type in the entire company name.  Can someone help me adjust this code for what I need?

Private Sub txtsrch_AfterUpdate()

```
If (txtsrch & vbNullString) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
rs.FindFirst "[lastname]=""" & txtsrch & """"
If rs.NoMatch Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, no such record '" & txtsrch & "' was found.", _
           vbOKOnly + vbInformation
Else
    Me.Recordset.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End If
rs.Close
txtsrch = Null
```

End Sub

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```
rs.FindFirst "[lastname] Like '*" & Replace(txtsrch,"'","''") & "*'"
```

You can vary where you put the wildcard (* for DAO) for starts with txtsrch, ends with txtsrch, or as illustrated, has txtsrch in the name.

Comment: Thank you Remou.   Why would I have a replace in there if I am not looking to replace anything.  I am a little confused. It is working perfectly though.

Comment: You are escaping occurrences of apostrophe in the string so you do not end up searching for `like '*D'Alembert*'`, which would cause an error.